# How do you create a long number from a List<Integer>?

Tags: java

How do you create a long number from a `List<Integer>` ?

From:

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

TO:

```
long = 1234567489
```

Thanks

Comment: `long result = 0; for (int d : ints) result = result * 10 + d;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr the method hereunder will help you only if your values are from 0 to 9. For all kinds of values, see Arvind's answer

---

Using stream reduction, you can achieve the same example as what has been proposed in the comments by @Dmitry Bychenko

```java
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

long result = ints.stream()
        .mapToLong(x -> x)
        .reduce(0, (prev, current) -> prev * 10 + current);

System.out.println("result = " + result); // reduce = 123456789
```

However, if your list contains too many elements, you'll overflow the `Long.MAX_VALUE` and so I'd prefer to also give you this answer based on `BigInteger`

```java
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

BigInteger result = ints.stream()
        .map(BigInteger::valueOf)
        .reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, (prev, current) -> prev.multiply(BigInteger.TEN).add(current));

System.out.println("result = " + result); // reduce = 123456789123456789123456789123456789
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert your `List<Integer>` to a `Stream<Integer>` which you can map to `Stream<String>` and collect using `Collectors.joining()`. Finally, parse the collected (joined) string to `long` using `Long#parseLong`.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long x = Long.parseLong(
                        List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
                        .stream()
                        .map(String::valueOf)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining())
                    );
        
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
123456789
```